# when is it safe to remove `/dev/.tmp-block-*` files

Tags: linux, lvm, rm

i'm currently experimenting with temporary lvm-snapshots (that is: create a snapshot of an LV, do something with the snapshot (e.g. run a backup), then destroy the snapshot. something along the lines:

```
lvcreate --snapshot --name "SNAP" --size 2GB lv01
dobackup /dev/VG1/SNAP
lvremove -f /dev/VG1/SNAP
```

the new `SNAP` "disk" has been created as with devicenumber `254:10`.

now today i discovered, that i got a hidden device-file `/dev/.tmp-block-254:10` in my device-directory. i *assume* that this is a left-over from the LV creation/removal.

i ran `lvdisplay` but the device doesn't show up.
also it seems that now process is currently using it (checked with `fuser /dev/.tmp-block-254:10` and `lsof /dev/.tmp-block-254:10`).

can i safely remove this file (`rm /dev/.tmp-block-254:10`)?

Answer (score 0):

Being that it's a hidden file in /dev and no process is currently using it, I don't see how removing it would be a problem. My question is why do you need to remove it? It's not doing anything and it's probably not taking up and HD space, so I don't see where there is a need.

A better fix would be to install util-linux and then run update-initramfs. According to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/util-linux/+bug/378930 that seems to fix the issue.

Comment: i want to remove it, since my system-monitoring (`rkhunter`,...) does not like it; i'll check the `util-linux` trick